# Git Alias: append string to commit message

Tags: git, alias, commit

To prevent our CI system from building on every commit, we have to append `[skip ci]` at the end of each commit (`git commit -m "... [skip ci]"`).

Is it possible to make an Alias for that?

I have been playing with:

```
[alias]
  cms = !git commit -m "${1} \[skip ci\]" $1
```

Comment: Why do you want to _push_ (you can create whatever you want; CI can only build what you push to repository that it sees) commits that should not be built by CI?

Comment: Mainly meant for branches. Don't want to build on every push to a branch.

Comment: But then it won't be built when it graduates to master either. Consider instead configuring the CI so that it does not build all branches but only central branches (`master`, `develop`, `next` etc. depending on what you have) and branches that match some pattern. Then you can push to non-built branch for backup/sharing and to built branch if you want to see your version still builds in all configurations. Even the same commit if you later decide you do want to build it.

Comment: We currently have our CI server configured like that. It builds `master` and `dev/*/pu*` (where `dev/user.name/` is per-developer namespaces for feature branches). I quite like it. I can push under my name whatever I want for archival or sharing and when I want to test it's still compilable (we have 7 target platforms) I just push it to my private `pu`.

Comment: Jenkins can also be configured to merge and push after build, so you could configure it so that say `pu/*` is built and if the build passes, merged into `master` (to which direct push would be prohibited with hook on the server, e.g. using [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/). That would ensure that only changes that build (and tests pass, possibly) are merged into `master`. I am sure other CI systems can be configured similarly; or you can always just write the commands into the script the CI server runs.

Comment: Thanky @JanHudec for the idea, I like it. However, this is going in a different direction. There are also other kind of commands I can attach to a commit, therefore I would like an answer to my question :)

Comment: That's why I wrote it as comments, not answer. Because it is not answer to the question as written.

Answer (score 2):

[Commit Message Hooks](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html)

Instead of an alias I would consider prompting the user with y/n if they want to skip CI or not from a hook.

My bash mojo is not good enough to know if what you are trying to accomplish is possible via a Git Alias.

Really really rough sample code.  Working, but doesn't cover all cases.

Put this in .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg and make sure it is executable

```
#!/bin/sh
exec < /dev/tty
echo "Skip CI?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"
do
   case ${yn} in
      "Yes")
         echo "[skip ci]" >> $1
         break;;
      "No")
         break;;
   esac
done
```

This is what happens when you run commit.  If you type "2" for no, the commit goes through normally, if you type "1" then it adds your skip ci message.  A proper solution would need to be extended to handle things like Merge commits, commit templates, etc.

```
(master)$ git commit -m "also junk"
Skip CI?
1) Yes
2) No
#? 1
[master bfa5200] also junk [skip ci]]
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 bar
me@myvm:/scratch/commit_msg  (master)$ git log 
commit bfa5200096f7251e2dc8fc457af81c59519901f3
Author: Andrew C <andrew.c@nowhere.com>

    also junk
    [skip ci]
```

Comment: How do you do that? Do you have an example code? Is it possible with Alias'?

Answer (score 0):

While not exactly what you asked for, I found a public [gist](https://gist.github.com/jpalmieri/cb6271004127633a133e9606ddba58b1) that adds a git alias so that you can prepend the "[skip ci]" after creating a commit.

Hats off to the author of the gist; I did not come up with this solution, but I verified that it works!

First add the new alias:

```sh
$ git config --global alias.skip-ci '!git reset && COMMIT_MSG=`git show --format=format:%B -s` && git commit --allow-empty --amend -m "[skip ci] $COMMIT_MSG"'
```

Then it can be used liked

```sh
$ git commit -m "Updated README.md"
$ git skip-ci
$ git push
```